# How to lift up the state from the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for some guidance in this react code
I have a ActionsDropDownWidget with a bunch of dropdown items being passed as children to it.

```
<DropdownMenu
                testId="actions-menu"
                trigger={({ triggerRef, ...props }) => (
                    <Button
                        appearance="subtle"
                        {...props}
                        iconBefore={<VerticalOverflowIcon label="more" />}
                        ref={triggerRef}
                    />
                )}
            >
                {children}
            </DropdownMenu>
```

Here is how I pass the children to ActionsDropDownWidget

```
<ActionsDropDownWidget attachment={attachment} onDeleteAttachment={onDeleteAttachment}>
                <CustomerDropdownActions
                    attachment={attachment}
                    onAttachmentDownload={onAttachmentDownload}
                    onCopyAttachmentName={onCopyAttachmentName}
                    onDeleteAttachment={onDeleteAttachment}
                />
            
        </ActionsDropDownWidget>
```

Here what is being rendered from CustomerDropdownActions

```
<DropdownItemGroup hasSeparator testId="negative-actions">
                <DropdownItem
                    onClick={(_) => setOpenDialog(true)}
                    elemBefore={
                        <TrashIcon label={t("confirmation_modal.negative_action.text")} testId={"trash-button"} />
                    }
                    description={t("action_dropdown.delete_attachment.description")}
                >
                    {t("action_dropdown.delete_attachment.text")}
                </DropdownItem>
            </DropdownItemGroup>
            {showConfirmationModal}
```

Now when the dropdown is rendered and so are the children in it.

When I click on the child above, its `onClick` tries to update the state. However, that state isn’t reflected and so the Dialog does not open.

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: where have you passed this as prop to children or are you using context API... 
  setOpenDialog I am not able to figure out this is not being passed as prop anywhere

Comment: @AdarshRaj I was managing the state wrongly. I corrected my problem and gave an answer below. I did a react rookie mistake.

Comment: it was not at all clear lol

Comment: @AdarshRaj you are right, Maybe I should have added more context about the problem.

Comment: can u refer me to atlassian? i am mern dev having ten months exp , batch of 2022 graduating in three months

Comment: Sure. Send me your resume.

Comment: mailed you thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the prop drilling took the best out of me.

1. The first mistake was in `ActionsDropDownWidget` that it wasn't a react functional component so I couldn't manage the state in there.

   **Fix?**

   > So what I did was to wrap the `ActionsDropDownWidget` in a wrapper
   > functional component.
2. The second mistake was I missed passing the event callback back to the parent to open the dialog box.

   ```
    <DropdownItem
       onClick={(_) => setOpenDialog(true)} << I should've called the parent callback here.
   ```

   **Fix?**

   > In the child components `CustomerActions` and `AgentActions` I tell
   > the parent via a callback function to show the modal. Since the parent
   > `ActionsDropdDownWidget` is now a functional component, I managed my
   > state there. So when child components send a event via the callback, I
   > update a variable called `openDialog` and it renders the modal.

Sketch

[image: Here is a sketch]